# Swagger doesn't generate object from yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I'm new in swagger.
I have a few yaml files and I try to genetare code, using swagger plugin in Intellij.
When I generate it, I have errors `cannot find symbol`. The symbol that he can't find is

```
TS29510NnrfNFManagementYamlcomponentsschemasFqdn
```

But this is wrong. Really he is looking for symbol

```
$ref: TS29510_Nnrf_NFManagement.yaml#/components/schemas/Fqdn
```

`Fqdn` is not generated (I think because it's type is not object).
But why generator can't find this symbol?

In yaml Fqdn looks like this:

```
Fqdn:
  type:
    - string
    - array
  items: {}
```

Comment: _"I think because it's type is not object"_. Nope, it's because `type` is a list of types rather than a single type. Type list is supported in OpenAPI 3.1 (the latest OpenAPI Specification version released in February 2021) but is not supported in OpenAPI 3.0 and 2.0.

Comment: @Helen how can I check version of OpenAPI? I use swagger-codegen-maven-plugin of version 3.0.25. But I don't explicitly include OpenAPI.

Comment: OpenAPI version is specified in your YAML file itself: `openapi: 3.x.x` is OpenAPI 3, `swagger: '2.0'` is OpenAPI 2. According to the info in your question, you use **OpenAPI 3.0**.

Answer (score 1):

You basically answered yourself. Object Fqdn is invalid that's why it can't generated or referenced. Simply change object declaration and enjoy working code :)

```
Fqdn:
  type: object
  properties:
    items:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped me. And I also understood the ligic how are objects defined in yaml.